# how to compare name of data member of class not their value

Tags: c++, string

how to campare name of data member(not their value), sending as a argument from function.
The example code  is as follows.

```
class Example
{
  private:
   std::string value;

  public:
   void Set(const std:: string& MemberName)
   {
      if(MemeberName == value)
       {
         std::cout<<"Same Member Name";
       }
      else
      {
         std::cout<<"Not same Member name";
      }
   }
 ...
}
```

i did this way but not getting the required result.
Thansks for the help

Comment: You could compare addresses, but why would you do that?

Comment: Use `string("value")` (assuming the member name you're looking for is `value`). C++ doesn't really provide for introspection.  You need to know your member names and refer to them directly in your C++ source.  The member names aren't available as strings at runtime.  If you want that connection, you have to build it yourself.

Comment: i need to compare the name because after this i have to set values from outside to the same datamember.

Comment: Depending on what you're doing, you might also consider using a `map<string, string>` or similar.  How general is this setter?

Comment: @user2696156 You can't do that. Probably you should use a `std::map<std:string,std:string>` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be

```
if(MemeberName == "value")
{
    std::cout<<"Same Member Name";
}
else
{
    std::cout<<"Not same Member name";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In case you want to find out whether it is the exactly same object, you might use the address, where it is stored:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

std::string g;

void foo(const std::string& arg)
{
    if (&arg == &g)                                        // compares addresses
        std::cout << "same object" << std::endl;
    if (arg == g)                                          // compares values 
        std::cout << "same value" << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    g = "abc";
    foo(g);
    return 0;
}
```

Note that when you pass by reference, you are actually working with the same object (no copy is being created) and thus when you use `&` operator you can retrieve the address of original object. This example prints both `same object` and `same value`.

Comment: I don't think that's what they're doing.  It seems more likely they're doing `object->set("foo", "bar")` hoping to set the member `foo` in the object to the value `bar`.

Comment: @JoeZ: It was asked in quite confusing way.

Comment: True.  But their later clarification I think makes it clear that what they want to do is closer to `arg == string("g")` in the context of your example above.